# Maven support in Mule Studio

Tags: maven, mule

Mule Studio is afaik supposed to replace Mule IDE as the development tool for Mule ESB. I am trying to understand how I am supposed to get full Maven integration in Mule Studio. All tutorials I find show how to create and package project inside the IDE but that is not workable for me as I need Maven for dependency management, automated builds and so on.

Basically I would like the same Maven support as in Mule IDE with m2eclipse. Maybe I am totally off base? Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks,
Olof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>This is a much required and expected feature: [STUDIO-1393](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/STUDIO-1393). Please vote it up!</strike>

**Update:**

Check the following instructions: [m2eclipse in MuleStudio](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3STUDIO/Exporting+Studio+to+Maven)

Comment: I don't see how I could have missed the Jira-issue. Anyway, my vote is in. Thanks!